# How inheritance works with friend classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, virtual-functions

I know that this topic has many answers but I don't understand why exactly my code works:

```
class Printer;

struct Base {
    virtual void foo1() = 0;
    virtual void foo2() = 0;
};
class Derived1 : Base
{
private:
    void foo1() override {
        cout << "derived1 calls foo1" << endl;
    }
    friend class Printer;
public:
    void foo2() override {
        cout << "derived1 calls foo2" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived2 : public Derived1 {
    void foo2() override {
        
        cout << "derived2 calls foo2" << endl;
    }
};
 
struct Printer {
    void print() {
        Derived2* d = new Derived2();
        d->foo1();
        d->foo2();
    }
};
```

In general the code is composed of a base type `Base` that is supporting two pure virtual methods, `Derived1` is the class that inherits and implements the Base interface, it friends the `Printer` class and marks the implementation of the `foo1`as private, thus class Derived2 has no access to the method `foo1` when inheriting from `Derived1`. But in the print method of class `Print`, I can use both of the functions of Derived1 via pointer to Derived2. Why is it happening? isn't the member inaccessible?

Side question: is there a way to mark methods in derived class as 'finished' (i.e., only their override method may not be overridden in classes inherited from the derived class)?

Answer (score 1):

The friendship isn't being inherited. Class Printer is a friend of Derived1 so has access to Derived1::foo1() via class Derived2. It's class Derived2 that can't call Derived1::foo1() because Derived1::foo1() is private.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it happening? isn't the member inaccessible?

No, you made it accessible:

```
  friend class Printer;
```

That's what a `friend` declaration does, after all. That's its sole mission in C++: to make private class members accessible to some other class, that otherwise wouldn't have access to them.

> Side question: is there a way to mark methods in derived class as
> 'finished' (i.e., only their override method may not be overridden in
> classes inherited from the derived class)?

That's sounds like a `final` specifier.

Comment: From what I understand friendship is not inherited. that is why it is strange for me.

Comment: Inheritance, and friendship, are completely separate things.